# False sharing and volatile

Tags: java, caching, false-sharing

Good day, I recently found an annotation introduced in Java 8 called **Contended**. From this mailing [list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2012-November/007309.html) I read what is false sharing and how annotation allows objects or fields to allocate an entire cache line.

After some research I found that if two cores store the same cache line and one of them modify it then the second one has to reread entire line from main memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol. But it still unclear for me why hardware forces CPU to reread it. I mean that is why we do have a volatile keyword in Java right ? If variable is declared as volatile then threads will skip this variable from cache and always read/write it from/to main memory. If hardware forces cpu to reread cache lines after every write then how data inconsistency is possible in multi threaded applications?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
After some research I found that if two cores store the same cache line and 
one of them modify it then the second one has to reread entire line from main memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol.
```

This is not correct. The cache is the source of truth because caches (at least on X86) are always coherent. So in theory a cacheline never needs to be read from main memory; it could always be served from the one of the CPU caches. If a different CPU cache would need a cacheline, it can just read the value from the other caches. With MESI it can happen that a cacheline is flushed to main memory when the cacheline is in modified state and a different CPU wants to read it; but otherwise no communication with main memory is needed. This is because MESI doesn't support dirty sharing; MOESI solves that problem.

```
 But it still unclear for me why hardware forces CPU to reread it. 
 I mean that is why we do have a volatile keyword in Java right ?
```

Caches on the X86 are always coherent. No special CPU instructions are needed for this; it is out of the box behavior. So it can't happen that e.g. the value A=1 is written to some cacheline, while a later read still sees the old value A=0.

```
 If variable is declared as volatile then threads will skip this variable 
 from cache and always read/write it from/to main memory. 
 If hardware forces cpu to reread cache lines after every write then how data inconsistency is possible in multi threaded applications?
```

This is not correct. Caches are the source of truth; there is no 'force reading from main memory'. There are special instructions that can bypass the CPU caches called non temporal loads and stores, but they are not relevant for this discussion.

The purpose of volatile is to make sure that the ordering with respect to other loads and stores to different addresses is preserved and that a stores are visible to other threads.

In case of false sharing; if the CPU's modify different parts of the same cacheline and a CPU need to write and the other CPU has just written to it, the first CPU needs to invalidate the cacheline on the other CPU with a RFO (Request For Ownership) once the write hits the linefillbuffer and it can't continue with the write until this RFO has been acknowledged. But as soon as the other CPU wants to write to that cacheline, it needs to send a RFO and wait for acknowledgement.

So you get a lot of cache coherence traffic between the different CPU's.. continuously fighting over the same cacheline. And if you are out of luck, there are no out of order instructions the CPU can execute, so effectively the CPU's will be mostly idle even though you have 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful explanation, It changed the way I think about volatile, till this day I though atomic write/read of volatiles are achieved using values directly from main memory. I am still not sure  "that a stores are visible to other threads". then how volatile makes value to be visible to other threads and why non volatile variables don't if caches are "Caches on the X86 are always coherent". Could you share some resources please so I can continue my research about this subject